# How can I debug services that don't run in the Unity Editor? (i.e. AdMob)

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

Is there a way I can debug problems with AdMob or other services that only run when the app is built and launched on a device rather than run in the Unity editor?  I'm currently having an issue where AdMob rewarded video ads crash my app and I'm not sure how to get the logs from my iPhone.  When run in the Unity editor the test ads won't display so debugging there is out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode for iOS and ADB for android. You can build using "Development build" option for more debugging. Official apple info on debugging:

https://developer.apple.com/support/debugging/